# Log user details when accessing eclipse p2 repository

Tags: logging, eclipse-rcp, equinox, p2

We have a eclipse RCP product and we plan to create a P2 repository for performing product live update.  One requirement is to track the users of the product when they perform “Update software” from the p2 repository.  This is to track the users using our product and the version of the product they have and contact them personally if required.

Is there any configuration or set up that we shall include so that we can log the details of the users who have our product?

It shall be like the http access log. Basically i would like to know if p2 supports to log http requests from the user and write it in to a log file, i.e., when the user is accessing the p2 repository.

Kindly help to advice.

Comment: Like an http access log? You really at least need to have a sketch of the solution you want to pursue. If you just state your problem, the question too broad and hence out of scope for stackoverflow.

Comment: Apologies for not making my question clear.  Yeah, like http access log.  Basically i would like to know if p2 supports to log http requests from the user and write it in to a log file, i.e., when the user is accessing the p2 repository.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clear. Adding clarifications in a comment is not enough - a question must be clear without having to read through all the comments.

Comment: An http access log is a server feature, whereas p2 is a client side library. So what do you want: client side or server side logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Eclipse p2 repository may have some support for stats, what you are asking for may be accomplished by some file server features, as basically p2 repository is just folder with files accessed over HTTP or HTTPS.

Also there are online services like [bintray](https://bintray.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/view/statistics)